# What should I use to patch this gap between brick siding and top of foundation

Tags: concrete, foundation, siding, mortar

I have a small gap between the top of our foundation and the start of the brick siding in one isolated area and was wondering what the best material would be to fill this area. [image]

[image]

Comment: Is that mesh from the foundation sticking in there?

Comment: I’d probably try to grind that metal off a bit shorter then use some  similar colored mortar

Comment: The black color sticking out almost feels like an asphalt shingle type material.

Answer (score 1):

1. Take and angle grinder and cut out the metal as much as you can.   The part sticking out isn't doing anything.
2. Use an epoxy concrete kit to fill in the gap.
3. Skim on a layer of concrete patch - to even out the corner and cover epoxy.

I would not just fill this with a concrete patch.   It will even pop out of that gap.  The skim layer may eventually fail too but it will have no bearing on water getting in and can be repaired in minutes.

Comment: Wouldn't something with some give and take be better?  Like that gray rubbery stuff they put between large concrete slabs.  Or does epoxy concrete have some flex?

Comment: Repointing the mortar with a patching material or mortar is the correct way grind or chipping any loose material helps and provides a clean surface +

Comment: Thanks guys, repointing with some mortar mix is what I ended up doing.